# What factors influences one to make a decision?

Tags: free-will

What factors can influence one to make a decision. Like whether they realized they never made the decision before or they made the decision some times before that they (insert verb here) to do it again?

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is open to a philosophical response, but I will let it stand - to see what other users think.

Comment: People can use all kinds of reasons or. non-reasons (eg something new) to make a decision. It is almost impossible to.list those in a descriptive and /or prescriptive manner

Answer (score 0):

Decision-making is actually problem-solving. A decision is a solution to a problem you face.

First, you need knowledge, understanding and an evaluation of the current circumstances. What is wrong? What would you like to change?

Second, you need to come up with options, optional ideas for a solution. You may remember similar situations from your past and how you solved or failed to solve them. You may also come up with new ideas you have never tried before.

Third, you need to evaluate your options against your preferences. You want to find the most optimal solution with the best potential for solving the problem with least effort, loss of resources or other negative consequences.